# Unable to start Jboss version 7.4.9 in Eclipse 2022-09

Tags: java, spring-boot, eclipse, jboss, jboss7.x

I am working on updating our java/Spring boot application from java 1.8 to java 17 and to spring 6. As part of this I have updated the eclipse version from Neon to 2022-09 and Jboss server in Eclipse to 7.4.9. But currently I am facing an issue while starting the jboss server in my local, it is throwing error within a few seconds after the server is started.

Even though it is throwing FileNotFoundException, it is not defined which file is missing. I have compared the latest jboss standalone xml file with my old working jboss standalone file and found no lead, deployments section is removed from standalone xml. Provided full access server.log/audit.log and to all the folders inside standalone folder in Jboss directory also did not help and server.log is also not having much details regarding the error. Tried searching through the internet and did not get any solution for this issue.

```
Failed to read or configure the org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to instantiate class "org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler" for handler "FILE"
at org.jboss.loamanager@2.1.18.Final-redhat-0000.//org.jboss.logmanager.config.AbstractPropertyConfiguration$ConstructAction.lambda$validate$2(AbstractPropertyConfiguration.java:122
at org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.18.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.logmanager.config.WrappedAction.execute(WrappedAction.java:42)
at org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.18.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.logmanager.config.AbstractPropertyConfiguration$ConstructAction.validate(AbstractPropertyContaguration.java:118
at org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.18.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.logmanager.config.LogContextConfigurationImp1.doPrepare(LogContextConfigurationImpl.java:336)
at org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.18.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.logmanager.config.LogContextConfigurationImpl.prepare(LogContextConfigurationImpl.java:289)
at org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.18.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.logmanager.confiq.LoqContextConfigurationImpl.commit(LoqContextConfigurationImpl.java:298)
at org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.18.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyContigurator.java:546)
at org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.10.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyContigurator.java:97)
at org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.18.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.readConfiguration(LogManager.java:170)
at org.jboss.Logmanager@2.1.18.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.readConfiguration(LogManager.java:132)
java.Logging/java.util.Logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration
java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java.395)
java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivilege(AccessController.java:318)
java.logging/java.util.Logging.LogManager.ensurelogManager.java.logging/java.util.logging.LogManager.getlogManager(LogManager.java:431)
jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java.457)
Caused by.java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
redhat-00001//org.jboss.logmanager.config.AbstractPropertyConfigurationsConstructAction.lambda$validate$2(AbstractPropertyConfiguration.java:120)
Caused by.java.io.FileNotFoundException.(The handle is invalid)
at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native.Method)
at Java.Base/Java.10.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java.293)
at Java.base/Java.10.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java.235)
at org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.18.Final-redhat-00001//org-jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingfileHandler.setFil.(PeriodicRotatingFileHandler.java.109)
org.jboss.logmanager@2.1.18.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandler.setFileName(FileHandler.java.189.a.org-jboss.logmanager@2.1.18.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:119.a.org-jboss.logmanager@2.1.18.Final-redhat-00001//or..jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandlor.<init.(PeriodicRotatingFileHandler.java.77)
```

Comment: Have you made the required Java 17 configuration changes mentioned in the Notes at the bottom of https://access.redhat.com/articles/6978703 ?

Comment: No need for JBOSS anymore.  Run your Spring Boot app as an executable JAR and ditch the JEE server.

Answer (score 0):

Spring 6 requires Jakarta EE 9.1+. JBoss EAP 7.4 is a Jakarta EE 8 container. You can't deploy Spring 6 applications on JBoss EAP 7.4. You'd have to use [WildFly 28](https://wildfly.org) if you want to use Spring 6.

That said, the error you're seeing; I'm not sure what is happening there. I've never seen that before, but maybe it's a side-affect of attempting to use Spring 6 with JBoss EAP 7.4.